# Is there modifications to VBA change event that will include value changes driven from a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

My Pivot Data is in Sheet B that contains a column with a Boolean flag. The Boolean flag is controlled using a cell in Sheet A that helps end user filter on specific geographies. I need the change vba code to also pick up value changes driven from the boolean flag

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
 ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide information about what values should be changed? How they should be defined by boolean flag? At this moment I see that there is only code, that refreshes all workbook, when any part of worksheet is changed. Actually what problem should be solved?

Comment: You can use the Target.column is the column of boolean flag !

Comment: You would monitor for changes on SheetA, looking at whatever range has the cells the user could modify

Comment: Column C on Sheet B updates when Cell B4 on Sheet A is updated to a new territory value (Area, Region, Territory) .  The Boolean is flagging all rows that equal to Cell B5 (ex B5 = Southern California).  My desired output would be to have the pivot table refresh when I update Cell B4 and/or B5. Thank you for helping, pretty new to VBA

Comment: Cell B4 and B5 on Sheet A are restricted using data validation list type.  When I applied the VBA to Sheet A, it ran but the pivot table did not refresh